# Is it feasible to have a variable number of views in a UITableViewCell prototype with dynamic height?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have begun to implement a UITableViewCell that has dynamic height based on its content following [this example](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html). And so I have a table cell with a UILabel, and the cell correctly sizes vertically to the proper height to accommodate the length of the label text.

However, I need to optionally include a couple of other views below the label. One of these views would be a custom UIView that would have variable/dynamic height. The other would be a UICollectionView with a fixed height. Here's the layout I'm going for...

[image]

So to clarify, not all rows in my table will show all views. Some will show just the label, some the label and the custom view, some the label, custom view, and the collection view.

At first I thought this would be as easy as including those optional views in my storyboard scene prototype cell, and then programmatically setting their hidden property to YES or NO depending on whether or not they were needed for the data row. That does hide/show them, but the vertical cell space does not "collapse" to reflect that they are hidden (I guess this works like CSS 'visible:hidden', and what I'm looking for is the 'display:none' equivalent).

For what it's worth, I'm also struggling to wrap my head around auto layout constraints. I've tried dynamically adding/removing the views to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, but things get really messed up in the UI. Not to mention I'm guessing this is going to be a performance problem when flinging thru the table rows.

The only other thing I can think to do is to create a separate cell prototype for all three combinations, but it just seems like duplication and could end up being harder to maintain in the long run, but if that's the proper way to do this, then so be it.

So I guess my questions are (1) is what I'm trying to do feasible, (2) what if any performance problems might I hit, and (3) where/how would I put this code to do the dynamic hiding/showing of these optional views.

Thanks!

Comment: What you propose is easily done in fully dynamic UI code.  (In fact, I've done even more complex ones.)  I've never used a storyboard, though, so I have no idea how it would fit into that scheme.

Comment: To get the spacing/height to adjust, you need to adjust it, implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath and setting the frame of the views you want to adjust in size or position.  (Or perhaps you can wimp out and use auto-sizing -- I've dealt very little with that.)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with this kind of issue but working with a CollectionView. Since TableView and CollectionView are like cousins, may be I can give you some hints.

At first I set up the cell layout in the storyboard and put some constraints; it worked awfully.

So I created a class for the cell and built it programatically. **In the init method of the cell class** I alloc, init and add all the subViews needed. Then, **in the viewController**, in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, after calling dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier, I call a method that I wrote inside the cell class. This method arrange the cell's subviews. As HotLicks said above, you have to implement **heightForRowAtIndexPath**. In this delegate method you should calculate the height according to the subviews that the cell is showing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to configure three different prototype cells in your Storyboard, and give them each a different Reuse Identifier.  Then select the appropriate reuse identifier before dequeuing the cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  This will enable you to get each of your layouts correct in IB rather than in code, and avoids building/laying out subviews for each invocation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  But it comes with some drawbacks: you will have extra segues to hook up, and if an item at a given indexPath transitions from needing one layout to another, you will have to use `reloadItemsAtIndexPath:` to force the tableView to drop the existing cell and dequeue the correct type, which might have some weird (or possibly helpful?) animation effects.